# Magento 1.9.1 Upgraded to 1.9.2 via Magento Connect

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, security, magento-connect, ce-1.9.2.0

I want to upgraded Magento 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 via Magento Connect.

I Updatet the Packet "Mage_All_Latest", which works without any error or warning.

After going back to the Admin Panel, my Admin Footer shows following Version

[image]

But when i open Magento Connect, it shows following Versions: [image]

**So my question is: Did the update work, or is my Magento still 1.9.1.1?
And how can i check if my Magento includes the new Security Patch?**

I already cleared Caches.

Comment: what your question.?please explain brief

Comment: I think the question is clear. Magento connect shows version 1.9.1.1 for the core packages even though the update seems to be applied. That being said, I have no idea because I never updated Magento using connect and would not recommend it either.

Comment: @AshvinMonpara edited question

Comment: What does it show in your admin panel?

Comment: Friends don't let friends do drugs, or Magento Connect upgrades. Magento Connect upgrades are notorious for doing partial upgrades, no upgrades or site destruction. The first time I tried it on a dev server, I had to do the upgrade all with force about three times before it took, and even then, it was missing a module because they forgot to include it in the lineup. I ended up doing what I should have in the first place, downloading the full install and untarring it over my installation, no further problems and the Prototype issues completely went away as well.

Comment: To be 100% sure your store is running the latest release code I would strongly advise restoring your 1.9.1 version and doing a manual upgrade to 1.9.2.1

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-magento/

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a common issue while using magento connect to update. It might be that a certain file did not get updated as stated in this stack post.

[Upgrade Magento 1.9.2 admin footer version number](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/upgrade-magento-1-9-2)

There are several locations where you can find something about versions. If you have a backup from before the update you could check if the version number has changed. You could check your database core_resource table, or check the etc/config.xml file. For example: app/code/local/[developer]/[plugin]/etc/config.xml

As for the patches. When an patch is installed this is listed in app/etc/applied.patches.list. The most recent patch is included in 1.9.2 so you probably won't see it here. If your upgrade went well you got the patch.

I'm currently updating my shops myself so if i run into anything helpfull i will add it here. I also have found this module which says that it can detect the applied patches. I don't know if it works but it might be worth giving a try.

https://www.magecomp.com/magento-applied-security-patches.html

As for the versioning in your footer, i'm not sure about this but you could try to rebuild your indexes, clear browsercache, manually clear cache folder or if you have something like Redis clear that too. Just to be sure that cache is not pointing you in the wrong direction

Hope this is of any help, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No, your Magento installation did not fully upgrade (which, apparently, is very common when using Magento Connect). [Downloading the latest install files](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and overwriting your existing installation will ensure a full upgrade, including the latest security patches (included patches will be listed in the download description).

Comment: As a note, security patches are available for those who don't want to do a full system upgrade, or to use prior to a version release.