# Magento not showing proper version in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, upgrade

I am tring to upgrade Magento Store `Magento 1.9.3.0` to `Magento 1.9.3.2`.
Its work properly and `app/Mage.php` also showing proper version but Admin Footer not showing proper version.

I tried following way to upgrade.

1) Using Replace all Core files

2) Using Magento Connect From Backend

3) Using `./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force`

But still not getting proper version

I tried to get magento version in SHELL it showing proper using `php -r "include 'app/Mage.php'; echo 'Magento version is: ', Mage::getVersion(); "`

But tried to upload following php file in root its show wrong version

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

try 
{
    echo 'Magento version is: '.Mage::getVersion();
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: OK try updating like from 1.9.3.0 to 1.9.3.1

Comment: then 1.9.3.1 to 1.9.3.2

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/upgrade-magento-1-9-2-admin-footer-version-number

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar I tried but not working in my case

Comment: cache cleared and checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following things,

1. Upload `index.php` file in your root from fresh magento 1.9.3.2.
2. Compare `.htaccess` code with fresh magento 1.9.3.2.

Because some time, during replacement it not updated and not showing proper version.

Comment: Let me check your solution

Comment: If you face any issue, discussed here as well.