# Upgrading CE from 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: upgrade

We have no changes to core files.

I am trying to upgrade a remote development site from 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.4.

After making a backup of all files, I uploaded the contents of the magento folder in `magento-1.9.2.4-2016-02-23-06-03-22.zip` to the web root.

After the upload was complete, I loaded the front end home page URL, then checked the back end, and the version remained @ 1.9.2.2.

Nothing was broken, but wondering what final step I need to do to complete the upgrade?

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: No, @PYYick, but after running `Flush Magento Cache` the version remains @ `1.9.2.2`. I did flush the cache before the upgrade process began.

Comment: So, I found a reference for you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/upgrade-magento-1-9-2-admin-footer-version-number

Comment: Note: next time you can upgrade core via Magento Connect, rather than complete file overwrite

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To confirm you have upgraded all your code you can check your app/Mage.php file to confirm your new version is in place.

```
cat app/Mage.php | grep version -A 12
```

This will return a string that gives you the version number from Magento

```
 public static function getVersionInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '9',
            'revision'  => '3',
            'patch'     => '3',
            'stability' => '',
```

To confirm all your cache is cleared you can remove the files in your var/cache folder as well as making sure REDIS or Memcache is cleared